# Copy one row to multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I tried googling it and couldn't find a simple answer. How do I take one row and apply it to multiple rows? For example in one row I have 'State" and I want to copy it in the same column just all the way down (multiple rows).

I am using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift-click the entire column (or range of rows), and then hit Fill->Down.

Though, where `Fill` is depends on what version of Excel you're running.

On 2007, Fill is located on the top right of the Home tab on the ribbon, in the Editing control box.

Comment: Excel 2007 is what I am using

Comment: I edited my answer. For future reference, questions of this reference should be asked on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

First Select to copy the Row which is to be copied from its next row. example - A1 to E1 is to be copied from A2:E2 to A420:E420

Then press Ctrl+G for GOTO option and enter destination cell number Example A420 and press to go there

From The cell number A420, Press Ctrl+Shift and Up Arrow and then all the cells between A420 to Cell Number A1 will be selected to copy .

Again press Shift+Down arrow one step to deselect The First Row / CELL A1 Row which has the content to copy from A2 Row to A420 Row.

Now press ENTER button bywhich the first row/ has been copied upto A420 Row